# Add top-level account for both Income (Revenue) and Expenses - Other (Non-Operating) Income And Expenses (GNU Cash)

Tags: gnucash

How do I create a top-level account in GNU Cash that can hold both Income *and* Expenses in its subaccounts?

IFRS (and US GAAP) don't directly publish example Chart of Accounts, but I find it common to use some standard top-level account number prefixes. For example:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chart_of_accounts#Example_Chart_of_Accounts
- https://www.ifrs-gaap.com/universal-chart-accounts-0

```
1.0.0 - Assets
2.0.0 - Liabilities
3.0.0 - Equity
4.0.0 - Operating Revenue
5.0.0 - Operating Expenses
6.0.0 - Other (Non-Operating) Income And Expenses
 \_ 6.1.0 Other Revenue And Expenses
   \_ 6.1.1 Other Revenue
   \_ 6.1.2 Other Expenses
```

GNU Cash says that an account must be one of [five account types](https://gnucash-docs-rst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/C/ch_accts.html?highlight=account%20types):

> As we saw in the previous chapter, accounting is based on 5 basic account types: Assets, Liabilities, Equity, Income and Expenses.
>
> ...
>
> A GnuCash account must have a unique name (that you assign) and one of the predefined GnuCash “account types”. There are a total of 12 account types in GnuCash. These 12 account types are based on the 5 basic accounting types; the reason there are more GnuCash account types than basic accounting types is that this allows GnuCash to perform specialized tracking and handling of certain accounts. There are 6 asset accounts (Cash, Bank, Stock, Mutual Fund, Accounts Receivable, and Other Assets), 3 liability accounts (Credit Card, Accounts Payable, and Liability), 1 equity account (Equity), 1 income account (Income), and 1 expense account (Expenses).
>
> source https://gnucash-docs-rst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/C/ch_accts.html?highlight=account%20types

While it's trivial to create the first five accounts in GNU Cash, I can't find a way to add a top-level account for `6.0.0 - Other (Non-Operating) Income And Expenses` -- which itself needs to hold both Income *and* Expense sub-accounts.

How can I structure my GNU Cash Accounts with a top-level account named `6.0.0 Other (Non-Operating) Income And Expenses` that can contain *both* an Income sub-account (eg `6.1.0 Other Revenue`) and Expenses (eg `6.1.2 Other Expenses`)?

Comment: GnuCash doesn't support an account that has both income and expenses. See the GnuCash [help page](https://www.gnucash.org/docs/v4/C/gnucash-guide/chapter_accts.html) on accounts. Since your CPA would probably not be using GnuCash reports directly when compiling the financial statements as per GAAP/IFRS standards, you can safely put the NO Income account under Income, the NO Expenses account under expenses and let your CPA compile them as needed.

Comment: See also https://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2022-December/104362.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what difficulty you're experiencing.  I'm using a current version of GnuCash, and I had no problems whatsoever in creating a new Top Level account called "Non Op" of type *Income*, to which I attached two child accounts of type *Income* and *Expense*.

I only created one transaction in each of the child accounts, but the rolled up effect of an amount in the income sub-account and an amount in the expenses sub-account had exactly the effect that I was expecting in the parent account.

[image]

If this isn't working for you, please provide further details of the feedback GnuCash is giving you.